# Cannot resolve symbol "CarmenFeature"

Tags: java, android, mapbox-android

I'm trying to use a fragment autocomplete UI from ---> https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/

but the IDE says that it can't resolve the symbol CarmenFeature and I don't know how to import that class or solve this exception

I've tried :

- to import ---> import com.mapbox.api.v4.models.CarmenFeature; 
  but I think that the API folder does not exist
- sync with gradle
- invalidate cache and restart
- rebuild project
- clean project

---

```
autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPlaceSelected( CarmenFeature carmenFeature) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onError(Status status) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that the class cannot be imported and loaded. You need to configure inside the `build.gradle` in the root of your project :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        ...
        maven
             {
              url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox'
             }
    }
}
```

and inside your `/app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...  
    // MAPBOX DEPENDENCIES
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.5.0@aar')
            {
                transitive=true
            }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.20.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.20.0')
            {
                transitive = true
            }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

}
```

this is enough to use the `CarmenFeature` class.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! everything seems to be working out fine. But since I'm just a beginner I've got no idea what have I just done. What would you recommend to learn these stuff?

Comment: Read about dependencies : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies